# Design Many to Many relationships in EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

**Hello**
I had a question.
If we want to have two tables (**Department** and **subject**) that have a many-to-many relationship between these two tables
Well, if we want to add a subject in the table of **Subject** that may be taught in one Department or more than one.  How can we design its tables?

this is my code :

```
public class Department 
 { 
    public int Id { get; set; } public string Name { get; set; } 
    public List<SubjectDepartment> SubmDepartmentsList { get; set;   } 
}


public class Subject 
{ 
  public int Id { get; set; } 
  public string Name { get; set; } 
  public int FacultyId { get; set; } public int DepartmetnId { get; set;} 
  public List<SubjectDepartment> SubjectDepartmentsList { get; set; }
 } 


public class SubjectDepartment
{
    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
    public Department Department { get; set; }
    public int SubjectId { get; set; }
    public Subject subject { get; set; }
}


 public class DepartmentMapping : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Department>
 {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Department> builder) { builder.HasKey(x => x.Id); }
 }

public class SubjecMapping : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Subject>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Subject> builder) { builder.HasKey(x => x.Id); }
}

public class SubjectDeparmentMapping : IEntityTypeConfiguration<SubjectDepartment>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<SubjectDepartment> builder) { builder.HasKey(x => new { x.DepartmentId, x.SubjectId }); builder.HasOne(x => x.Department).WithMany(x => x.SubmDepartmentsList).HasForeignKey(x => x.DepartmentId); builder.HasOne(x => x.subject).WithMany(x => x.SubjectDepartmentsList).HasForeignKey(x => x.SubjectId); }
}
```

searching and red the microsoft documentation

Comment: Can you share what your code ?

Comment: For me your design is correct, what kind of error you got ?

Comment: Well, the error that I didn't receive is the issue of data storage, how and in which table should I save it, for example (if we want to register a subject that is taught in two departments at the same time in the database)

Comment: You're not showing your Department class but you can either use the navigation collections in Department and Subject to do your CRUD, or you can add a junction class that contains the two objects and their keys. The choice is yours but I prefer the junction class.

Comment: I have put my code example in the skin and there is department class in it. Then if we want to do CRUD operation on the interface class where we have foreign keys and we cannot store data in the foreign key.

Comment: Please show this as a [mre]. It's unclear what you're asking. I *think* all you need to do is add or remove `SubjectDepartment` objects.

Comment: Something that threw me off with M2M relationships was that EF Core created a join/junction table for me, even when I had already defined one under a different name. It really wants to use the one that it generates, so maybe that will help you.

Answer (score 1):

- Suppose you have a Subject (id:1, Name: Subject1  ) already created and a departement already created Departement  (id :1 ,Name : Departement1 )

  ```
  context.SubjectDepartments.Add(new SubjectDepartment{DepartmentId = 1,SubjectId=1  };
  context.SaveChanges();
  ```
- Suppose you have a Subject (id:1, Name: Subject1  ) already created and a departement not yet created Departement  (Name : "new departement" )

  ```
   var subjectDepartment= new SubjectDepartment{SubjectId=1,Departement = new Departement {Name ="new departement"}};
  context.SubjectDepartments.Add(subjectDepartment);
  context.SaveChanges();
  ```
- Suppose you have a  new Subject (  Name: new subject)  and a departement already created Departement  (id :1 ,Name : Departement1 )

  ```
  var subjectDepartment= new SubjectDepartment{Subject= new Subject{Name="new subject"} ,DepartementId=1};
  context.SubjectDepartments.Add(subjectDepartment);
  context.SaveChanges();
  ```